# ClassNotFoundException across different machines

Tags: java, client-server, messaging, chatroom

I am trying to write a messaging application in java, but keep getting an error. When I run the client on server on the same device, I get the same message. However, when I run the client and server on the same device, the client can receive messages from the server, but is unable to send a message. If I do try to send a message from the separate machine, I get the following errors:

```
Server has close the connection: java.io.EOFException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ChatMessage
```

I do not know what this error means, and do not know how to fix it. I would very much appreciate some help and precise instructions on how to fix this error, and prevent it in the future.

Server Class:

```
public class Server {
    // a unique ID for each connection
    private static int uniqueId;
    // an ArrayList to keep the list of the Client
    private ArrayList<ClientThread> al;
    // if I am in a GUI
    private ServerGUI sg;
    // to display time
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    // the port number to listen for connection
    private int port;
    // the boolean that will be turned of to stop the server
    private boolean keepGoing;

    private Socket socket;


    /*
     *  server constructor that receive the port to listen to for connection as parameter
     *  in console
     */
    public Server(int port) {
        this(port, null);
    }

    public Server(int port, ServerGUI sg) {
        // GUI or not
        this.sg = sg;
        // the port
        this.port = port;
        // to display hh:mm:ss
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        // ArrayList for the Client list
        al = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
    }

    public void start() {
        keepGoing = true;
        /* create socket server and wait for connection requests */
        try 
        {
            // the socket used by the server
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            // infinite loop to wait for connections
            while(keepGoing) 
            {
                // format message saying we are waiting
                display("Server waiting for Clients on port " + port + ".");

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();      // accept connection
                // if I was asked to stop
                if(!keepGoing)
                    break;
                ClientThread t = new ClientThread(socket);  // make a thread of it
                al.add(t);                                  // save it in the ArrayList
                t.start();
            }
            // I was asked to stop
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
                for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                    ClientThread tc = al.get(i);
                    try {
                    tc.sInput.close();
                    tc.sOutput.close();
                    tc.socket.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException ioE) {
                        // not much I can do
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                display("Exception closing the server and clients: " + e);
            }
        }
        // something went bad
        catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = sdf.format(new Date()) + " Exception on new ServerSocket: " + e + "\n";
            display(msg);
        }
    }       
    /*
     * For the GUI to stop the server
     */
    protected void stop() {
        keepGoing = false;
        // connect to myself as Client to exit statement 
        // Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        try {
            new Socket("localhost", port);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // nothing I can really do
        }
    }
    /*
     * Display an event (not a message) to the console or the GUI
     */
    private void display(String msg) {
        String time = sdf.format(new Date()) + " " + msg;
        if(sg == null)
            System.out.println(time);
        else
            sg.appendEvent(time + "\n");
    }
    /*
     *  to broadcast a message to all Clients
     */
    private synchronized void broadcast(String message) {
        // add HH:mm:ss and \n to the message
        String time = sdf.format(new Date());
        String messageLf = time + " " + message + "\n";
        // display message on console or GUI
        if(sg == null)
            System.out.print(messageLf);
        else
            sg.appendRoom(messageLf);     // append in the room window

        // we loop in reverse order in case we would have to remove a Client
        // because it has disconnected
        for(int i = al.size(); --i >= 0;) {
            ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
            // try to write to the Client if it fails remove it from the list
            if(!ct.writeMsg(messageLf)) {
                al.remove(i);
                display("Disconnected Client " + ct.username + " removed from list.");
            }
        }
    }

    // for a client who logoff using the LOGOUT message
    synchronized void remove(int id) {
        // scan the array list until we found the Id
        for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
            ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
            // found it
            if(ct.id == id) {
                al.remove(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  To run as a console application just open a console window and: 
     * > java Server
     * > java Server portNumber
     * If the port number is not specified 1500 is used
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start server on port 1500 unless a PortNumber is specified 
        int portNumber = 1500;
        switch(args.length) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid port number.");
                    System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server [portNumber]");
                    return;
                }
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server [portNumber]");
                return;

        }
        // create a server object and start it
        Server server = new Server(portNumber);
        server.start();
    }

    /** One instance of this thread will run for each client */
    class ClientThread extends Thread {
        // the socket where to listen/talk
        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream sInput;
        ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
        // my unique id (easier for deconnection)
        int id;
        // the Username of the Client
        String username;
        // the only type of message a will receive
        ChatMessage cm;
        // the date I connect
        String date;

        // Constructore
        ClientThread(Socket socket) {
            // a unique id
            id = ++uniqueId;
            this.socket = socket;
            /* Creating both Data Stream */
            System.out.println("Thread trying to create Object Input/Output Streams");
            try
            {
                // create output first
                sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                // read the username
                username = (String) sInput.readObject();
                display(username + " just connected.");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + e);
                return;
            }
            // have to catch ClassNotFoundException
            // but I read a String, I am sure it will work
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            }
            date = new Date().toString() + "\n";
        }

        // what will run forever
        public void run() {
            // to loop until LOGOUT
            boolean keepGoing = true;
            while(keepGoing) {
                // read a String (which is an object)
                try {
                    cm = (ChatMessage) sInput.readObject();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    display(username + " Exception reading Streams: " + e);
                    break;              
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    display(e2.toString());
                    break;
                }
                // the messaage part of the ChatMessage
                String message = cm.getMessage();

                // Switch on the type of message receive
                switch(cm.getType()) {

                    case ChatMessage.MESSAGE:
                    broadcast(username + ": " + message);
                    break;
                case ChatMessage.LOGOUT:
                    display(username + " disconnected with a LOGOUT message.");
                    keepGoing = false;
                    break;
                case ChatMessage.WHOISIN:
                    writeMsg("List of the users connected at " + sdf.format(new Date()) + "\n");
                    // scan al the users connected
                    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                        ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
                        writeMsg((i+1) + ") " + ct.username + " since " + ct.date);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            // remove myself from the arrayList containing the list of the
            // connected Clients
            remove(id);
            close();
        }

        // try to close everything
        private void close() {
            // try to close the connection
            try {
                if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
            try {
                if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {};
            try {
                if(socket != null) socket.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        /*
         * Write a String to the Client output stream
         */
        private boolean writeMsg(String msg) {
            // if Client is still connected send the message to it
            if(!socket.isConnected()) {
                close();
                return false;
            }
            // write the message to the stream
            try {
                sOutput.writeObject(msg);
            }
            // if an error occurs, do not abort just inform the user
            catch(IOException e) {
                display("Error sending message to " + username);
                display(e.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Client Class:

```
public class Client  {

    // for I/O
    private ObjectInputStream sInput;       // to read from the socket
    private ObjectOutputStream sOutput;     // to write on the socket
    private Socket socket;

    // if I use a GUI or not
    private ClientGUI cg;

    // the server, the port and the username
    private String server, username;
    private int port;

    /*
     *  Constructor called by console mode
     *  server: the server address
     *  port: the port number
     *  username: the username
     */
    Client(String server, int port, String username) {
        // which calls the common constructor with the GUI set to null
        this(server, port, username, null);
    }

    /*
     * Constructor call when used from a GUI
     * in console mode the ClienGUI parameter is null
     */
    Client(String server, int port, String username, ClientGUI cg) {
        this.server = server;
        this.port = port;
        this.username = username;
        // save if we are in GUI mode or not
        this.cg = cg;
    }

    /*
     * To start the dialog
     */
    public boolean start() {
        // try to connect to the server
        try {
            socket = new Socket(server, port);
        } 
        // if it failed not much I can so
        catch(Exception ec) {
            display("Error connectiong to server:" + ec);
            return false;
        }

        String msg = "Connection accepted " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort();
        display(msg);

        /* Creating both Data Stream */
        try
        {
            sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException eIO) {
            display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + eIO);
            return false;
        }

        // creates the Thread to listen from the server 
        new ListenFromServer().start();
        // Send our username to the server this is the only message that we
        // will send as a String. All other messages will be ChatMessage objects
        try
        {
            sOutput.writeObject(username);
        }
        catch (IOException eIO) {
            display("Exception doing login : " + eIO);
            disconnect();
            return false;
        }
        // success we inform the caller that it worked
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * To send a message to the console or the GUI
     */
    private void display(String msg) {
        if(cg == null)
            System.out.println(msg);      // println in console mode
        else
            cg.append(msg + "\n");      // append to the ClientGUI JTextArea (or whatever)
    }

    /*
     * To send a message to the server
     */
    void sendMessage(ChatMessage msg) {
        try {
            sOutput.writeObject(msg);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            display("Exception writing to server: " + e);
        }
    }

    /*
     * When something goes wrong
     * Close the Input/Output streams and disconnect not much to do in the catch clause
     */
        private void disconnect() {
        try { 
            if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
        try {
            if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
        try{
            if(socket != null) socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do

        // inform the GUI
        if(cg != null)
            cg.connectionFailed();

    }
    /*
     * To start the Client in console mode use one of the following command
     * > java Client
     * > java Client username
     * > java Client username portNumber
     * > java Client username portNumber serverAddress
     * at the console prompt
     * If the portNumber is not specified 1500 is used
     * If the serverAddress is not specified "localHost" is used
     * If the username is not specified "Anonymous" is used
     * > java Client 
     * is equivalent to
     * > java Client Anonymous 1500 localhost 
     * are eqquivalent
     * 
     * In console mode, if an error occurs the program simply stops
     * when a GUI id used, the GUI is informed of the disconnection
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // default values
        int portNumber = 1500;
        String serverAddress = "localHost";
        String userName = "Anonymous";

        // depending of the number of arguments provided we fall through
        switch(args.length) {
            // > javac Client username portNumber serverAddr
            case 3:
                serverAddress = args[2];
            // > javac Client username portNumber
            case 2:
                try {
                    portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid port number.");
                    System.out.println("Usage is: > java Client [username] [portNumber] [serverAddress]");
                    return;
                }
            // > javac Client username
            case 1: 
                userName = args[0];
            // > java Client
            case 0:
                break;
            // invalid number of arguments
            default:
                System.out.println("Usage is: > java Client [username] [portNumber] {serverAddress]");
            return;
        }
        // create the Client object
        Client client = new Client(serverAddress, portNumber, userName);
        // test if we can start the connection to the Server
        // if it failed nothing we can do
        if(!client.start())
            return;

        // wait for messages from user
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        // loop forever for message from the user
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("> ");
            // read message from user
            String msg = scan.nextLine();
            // logout if message is LOGOUT
            if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGOUT")) {
                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.LOGOUT, ""));
                // break to do the disconnect
                break;
            }
            // message WhoIsIn
            else if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("WHOISIN")) {
                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.WHOISIN, ""));               
            }
            else {              // default to ordinary message
                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, msg));
            }
        }
        // done disconnect
        client.disconnect();    
    }

    /*
     * a class that waits for the message from the server and append them to the JTextArea
     * if we have a GUI or simply System.out.println() it in console mode
     */
    class ListenFromServer extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    String msg = (String) sInput.readObject();
                    // if console mode print the message and add back the prompt
                    if(cg == null) {
                        System.out.println(msg);
                        System.out.print("> ");
                    }
                    else {
                        cg.append(msg);
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    display("Server has close the connection: " + e);
                    if(cg != null) 
                        cg.connectionFailed();
                    break;
                }
                // can't happen with a String object but need the catch anyhow
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ChatMessage Class:

```
public class ChatMessage implements Serializable {

    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1112122200L;

    // The different types of message sent by the Client
    // WHOISIN to receive the list of the users connected
    // MESSAGE an ordinary message
    // LOGOUT to disconnect from the Server
    static final int WHOISIN = 0, MESSAGE = 1, LOGOUT = 2;
    private int type;
    private String message;

    // constructor
    ChatMessage(int type, String message) {
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
    }

    // getters
    int getType() {
        return type;
    }
    String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Note that I am able to send messages just fine if I load both the server and client on the same machine. If I load the server on one machine, and the client on another, however, the client can receive messages from the server, but the server cannot receive messages from the client. If I attempt to send a message from the client to the Server, it gives me the errors shown above.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: What is a stack trace?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors.

Comment: Post the entire error

Comment: I included everything else in the inital error statement

Comment: Are you sure you have ChatMessage class in both server and client?

Comment: Every Class is in the same package.

Comment: Are you getting this error on server or client?

Comment: It's a server error.

Comment: It means you don't have the class in Server side

Comment: How do I get the class in the Server then?

Comment: If you have the source files in the server, compile them and try running.

Comment: I'm a novice and I'm not sure how to do that. I don't have a seperate server. I have a package which contains the Server, ChatMessage, Client, ServerGUI, and ClientGUI classes. I'm able to send messages to the to and from the client to the server if they are both on the same machine, but if they are on different machines, the Server can send messages to the client, but the client cannot send messages to the server. If I attempt to do so, I get the errors listed above.

Comment: I can run the Server class, which starts a Server on my local machine with a default port. I can then start a Client from the ClientGUI. If I am on a separate machine on the same network, then I can just enter the IP of the machine I'm connecting to. I will have a successful connection to the server, but am disconnected the second I try to send a message.

Comment: Are you running your code from an IDE or command line?

Comment: I am running it from Eclipse.

Comment: It would be nice if you could share the code you use to start the server and client

Comment: Instead of using `System.out.println()` or `display()`, can you use `e.printStackTrace()` to print the whole exception stack traces in catch blocks? Because we need the full exception stack trace to debug the error properly

Comment: It did the following

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ChatMessage
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
 at com.liftedstarfish.lifte.gpschat.Server$ClientThread.run(Server.java:236)

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project in eclipse and rebuild again?

Comment: If it does not work, you can try running your code from command line. First go to the directory which has your code. Compile by `javac *.java`. Then run   `java Server`. Run your client `java Client`. See if you getting the error now

Comment: How do I clean a project?

Comment: Go to Project-->Clean. Then run the code.

Comment: I have figured out the problem It was actually quite simple. The project package was different on one machine than it was on another.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you found out